# Android email ACTION_CALL equivalent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am incorporating an email activity in my app and I'm wondering if it's possible to not have the user click the 'send button' but instead I have the mail app send the mail right away programatically. 
If you would compare it to using a call intent then you could say right now I am using ACTION_DIAL but I want to use ACTION_CALL.

I have looked into this:

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)

But this is not meant to work with a users email account. 
I'm kind of assuming it's not possible, but if anyone has any ideas, they would be most welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm kind of assuming it's not possible

Correct. There is no `Intent` action with those semantics. And, even if there were, there is no requirement that all email clients actually honor those semantics.